# In php my mysql select query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I created code for select query for MySQL in PHP.

The code:

```
$vericek4 = $baglanti2 -> prepare ("select no from urunlist where urunad like '%?%'");
$vericek4 -> bindParam(1, $aramayss);
$vericek4 -> execute();

$satirsay2 = $vericek4 -> rowCount();
```

I have data in `$aramayss`. But `$satirsay2` is null.

Comment: Never quote your parameters! It will never do what you think it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It "works".  It just doesn't do what you expect.  The `?` is in a string, so it is not substituted with the parameter value.

You can construct the `like` pattern using `concat()`:

```
select no from urunlist where urunad like concat('%', ?, '%')
```

Alternatively, add the wildcards in PHP, and just use:

```
select no from urunlist where urunad like ?
```

Comment: İ did it like you said but the code doesn't work

Comment: What does „the code doesn't work“ mean?